# Not able to affect look of html through external css

Tags: python, css, django, django-templates, atom-editor

I have a static folder in it i have css folder inside of that i have .css file which link to my base page which is extended to all pages,when i select an element and try to affect its property i am unable to do so like putting the table in the home page in center.EArlier also i tied to increase cell's width and height in table but it did not affect it immediatley then suddenly after a day by itsel the height and width of cells got set.What do i need to do to affect my template through external css.

Template the base.html page

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
{% load static %}

<html lang="en" dir="ltr">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Base</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static "css/mystyle.css"%}">
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">

  </head>
{%block Body_Block%}


<table>
HTML...code
</table>
{%endblock%}
```

settings.py

```
STATIC_DIR=os.path.join(BASE_DIR,"static")
STATIC_URL = '/static/'

STATICFILES_DIRS=[
     STATIC_DIR,
     '/var/www/static/',
]
```

css:

```
table{
margin: 0 auto;

}
```

Comment: Looks like a caching issue. Try disabling cache from the Network tab in browser dev tools.

Comment: Definitely a caching issue. Try clearing the cache or open your page on the incognito window.

Comment: Is the problem solved?

Comment: yes the answer worked

Answer (score 0):

It could be that you may be making the changes while the server is running, in which case the changes may not directly take place sometimes, unless you restart the server.

You can apply `static` file changes without restarting the server by doing the command

```
python manage.py collectstatic
```

You can read more on that [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/contrib/staticfiles/#collectstatic)